# Elastic search: Create tokens separated by either <space> or "-" and greater than 3 chars

Tags: elasticsearch

In my elastic search setup, I would like to create tokens separated by either " " or "-" and greater than 3 chars. 
I believe pattern tokenizer can work but I am not able to create the regular expression.

Please help me in regular expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the following regex in the **pattern** field of your **pattern tokenizer**:

`([^\s-]{3,})`

- The **\s** means any whitespace character.
- The **-** means the literal dash character.
- Putting the two of them between **[^** and **]** means match any character that isn't the ones in the list (in this case, anything **not whitespace and not a dash**)
- The **{3,}** means the previous match has to occur 3 times or more.
- The **parenthesis** around the entire statement means you want to capture what is inside, and the pattern tokenizer pulls its tokens from the matching groups of the regex.

You can play with this regex here and see how it will split your string:

https://regex101.com/r/2e9p34/1

**On a side note**, there may be other better ways to do this that will better handle edge cases you aren't thinking of, but I decided to answer your question exactly as you asked it. I highly recommend exploring all of the options ElasticSearch provides for its analyzers for your use case to see which one best fits your needs.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Lusid, The requirement changed a bit. Now they want to keep the whole value as a token as well along with the tokens identified by your suggested regex.
Can you please add this clause as well in the suggested regex?